# How to send email with attachment of file without extension?

Tags: c#, email, attachment, email-attachments

I created C# Console App and I can't send email with file attachment named "testfile" and has no extension.

It successfully sends, but with only the first attachment ("test.png")
How can I send this file?

Here is my code:

```
internal static void SendTest()
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("Punter@gmail.com", "Michael378@live.com",
                                       "Success", "Attachment email");

    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Punter@gmail.com",      "BrudoTass");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        string test1 = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.png";          //Picture
        string test2 = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testfile";   //File without extension
        var attachment1 = new Attachment(test1);
        var attachment2 = new Attachment(test2);

        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment1);
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment2);

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
```

Comment: I think that it relates to `gmail` policy about files. You can not send file(s) without extension.

Comment: I have just tried this with .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.5 and it works with both (using my network credentials of course). Your code works without an issue for me. I see both attachment with extension and without it. Which .NET framework version are you using and what exactly is in that file (I tried it both with empty extension-less file and one with some text in)?

Comment: This is probably not a thing but I think the default extension is a .file

Answer (score 0):

Try This way

```
        foreach (MessageAttachment ma in msg.Attachments)
        mail.Attachments.Add(BuildAttachment(ma));

        private Attachment BuildAttachment(MessageAttachment ma)
        {
            Attachment att = null;

            if (ma == null || ma.FileContent == null)
                    return att;

            att = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(ma.FileContent), ma.FileName + ma.FileType, ma.FileType.GetMimeType());
            att.ContentDisposition.CreationDate = ma.CreationDate;
            att.ContentDisposition.ModificationDate = ma.ModificationDate;
            att.ContentDisposition.ReadDate = ma.ReadDate;
            att.ContentDisposition.FileName = ma.FileName;
            att.ContentDisposition.Size = ma.FileSize;

            return att;
        }
```